# The coefficients of a positive current are radon measures

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, potential-theory

I am trying to understand the following proof:[image]

from page 9 of [this notes](http://bogomolov-lab.ru/G-sem/kolodziejwhole.pdf). I do not quite follow the logic here. So I guess the point is that $T \wedge \omega_{s}$ is a radon measure. Why is this true, isn't it just a top degree current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need (a) Riesz representation theorem; while Wikipedia is hardly a definitive source it will give you a good outline [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem).  What it comes down to is that you have a linear functional defined on a space of compactly supported forms, and these have a nice representation as Radon measures.

Comment: But if I understand correctly Riesz representation is for bounded linear functional on the space of compactly supported continuous functions, but here we only act on the space of compactly supported smooth functions. It makes sense only if $T \wedge \omega_{s}$ is of order $0$.

Comment: "Smooth" means continuous and all derivatives are continuous, so that's not really an issue.  But this is essentially why you described $T\wedge \omega _s$ as a top-order current.

Comment: Sorry,but I am confused. My understanding is that a distribution can only be extended to the space of compactly supported continuous functions if it's of order $0$, but I do not see how $T \wedge \omega_s$ is necessarily of order zero here. The point is that it only acts on smooth functions apriori, so I do not think Riesz is immediately applicable.

Comment: The comments in the notes prior to this theorem explain why $T\wedge \omega$ can be viewed as a Radon measure; I think (but I'm a bit pressed for time right now) that it comes down to the definition before proposition $1.3$ which tells you that $T \wedge \omega $ is proportional to a holomorphic mapping

Comment: I see. so it is basically required in the definition that $T \wedge \omega$ has to be a nonnegative measure. Thank you very much!